# How to specify multiple databases when connecting to DolphinDB Server with JDBC interface？

Tags: java, jdbc, dolphindb

My data is saved in multiple databases.

Can I specify the databasePath with multiple paths to DFS databases where various tables are saved?

That said, the script is as follows:

[image]

Comment: You might find [`DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F22%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple databases through the tableAlias of the JDBC interface, for example:

```
jdbc:dolphindb://192.168.1.55:8848?tableAlias=benchmark_kline_daily:dfs://ch_low_db/benchmark_kline_daily
```